# How do you stroke text using AttributedString in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, nsattributedstring

## iOS 15 includes support for [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring)

#### Example

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    func attributedString(string: String) -> AttributedString {
        var text = AttributedString(string)
        text.font = .largeTitle.bold()
        text.foregroundColor = .blue
        return text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(attributedString(string: "Hello"))
    }
}
```

[image: Attributed text]

Documentation mentions [**Attribute Scopes**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes)

> The AttributedString API defines keys for common uses, such as text
> styling, semantically marking up formattable types like dates and
> numbers, and hyperlinking. You can find these in the AttributeScopes
> enumeration, which contains attributes for Foundation, SwiftUI, UIKit,
> and AppKit.

Here's [strokeColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/uikitattributes/3784551-strokecolor) for the stroke color attribute, but it appears to do nothing.

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    func attributedString(string: String) -> AttributedString {
        var text = AttributedString(string)
        text.font = .largeTitle.bold()
        text.foregroundColor = .blue
        text.strokeWidth = 5
        text.strokeColor = .red
        return text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(attributedString(string: "Hello"))
    }
}
```

[image: Attributed text]

Additional docs:

- Foundation attributes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/foundationattributes
- SwiftUI attributes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/swiftuiattributes
- UIKit attributes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/uikitattributes
- AppKit attributes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/appkitattributes

Comment: Could be a bug, but what if you change `.strokeWidth = 5` to `.strokeWidth = -5`?

Comment: Good idea, but so far nothing ✌️ I tried it with a few values 5, -5, 5.0, and same results

Comment: Yeah, see Asperi's answer. I would describe this as a bug because Apple has done an incomplete job of the implementation here. They probably know, but I'd suggest filing a bug anyway so that they know you want this. Meanwhile you can just keep using NSAttributedString I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

`strokeWidth` in AttributedString doesn't work with SwiftUI.

I asked similar question on Twitter after WWDC 2021 and I got a reply from Foundation Engineer at Apple. This was the reply:

> .strokeWidth is an AppKit/UIKit defined attribute so it isn’t guaranteed to work with SwiftUI automatically. You can find all of the attributes supported by SwiftUI at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/swiftuiattributes

If you want to use stroked text with SwiftUI, you will need to use UIViewRepresentable view as a workaround. Create a UILabel and set a NSAttributedString with strokeWidth to attributedText property of UILabel.

Comment: Heard. ✌️ 

It's frustrating that they include strokeColor in AttributeScopes docs 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/uikitattributes

NSAttributedString works on iOS, but looking for something universal so I can get the same text effect on watchOS e.g. WKInterfaceLabel has support for attributed string, but it's not available thru SwiftUI only with a storyboard

Answer (score 2):

We have to use attributes from SwiftUI `AttributeScopes`.

Here are all attributes supported now by SwiftUI and (`stroke*` are not presented in the list, although it replicates some attributes from UIKit scope):

```
extension AttributeScopes {

    /// A property for accessing the attribute scopes defined by SwiftUI.
    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    public var swiftUI: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.Type { get }

    /// Attribute scopes defined by SwiftUI.
    @available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, *)
    public struct SwiftUIAttributes : AttributeScope {

        /// A property for accessing a font attribute.
        public let font: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.FontAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a foreground color attribute.
        public let foregroundColor: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.ForegroundColorAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a background color attribute.
        public let backgroundColor: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.BackgroundColorAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a strikethrough style attribute.
        public let strikethroughStyle: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.StrikethroughStyleAttribute

        /// A property for accessing an underline style attribute.
        public let underlineStyle: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.UnderlineStyleAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a kerning attribute.
        public let kern: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.KerningAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a tracking attribute.
        public let tracking: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.TrackingAttribute

        /// A property for accessing a baseline offset attribute.
        public let baselineOffset: AttributeScopes.SwiftUIAttributes.BaselineOffsetAttribute

        /// A property for accessing attributes defined by the Accessibility framework.
        public let accessibility: AttributeScopes.AccessibilityAttributes

        /// A property for accessing attributes defined by the Foundation framework.
        public let foundation: AttributeScopes.FoundationAttributes

        public typealias DecodingConfiguration = AttributeScopeCodableConfiguration

        public typealias EncodingConfiguration = AttributeScopeCodableConfiguration
    }
}
```

Comment: Good recap. 

It's frustrating that they include strokeColor in AttributeScopes docs 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/uikitattributes

Clearly it needs more love

Comment: Pay attention that by that reference [UIKit] is a scope ([Framework] section). There is similar for [SwiftUI] scope https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/swiftuiattributes

Comment: Yep, there're all scoped  Based on docs, feels like we can naturally expect the UIKit attributes to work on iOS regardless of SwiftUI



• [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/foundationattributes)

• [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/swiftuiattributes)

• [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/uikitattributes)

• [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/appkitattributes)