# NSAttributedString in watchOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, nsattributedstring, watchos

### Goal: Stroke text in watchOS with SwiftUI

With a storyboard project, [image: Create new storyboard project]

[WKInterfaceLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel) offers support for [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) via [setAttributedText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel/1620933-setattributedtext) which offers simple and easy support to stroke text.[image: Storyboard]

However, with a new project using SwiftUI,[image: New Project SwiftUI] [WKInterfaceLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel) isn't available outside of the nonexistent storyboard:

> Do not subclass or create instances of this class yourself. Instead, define outlets in your interface controller class and connect them to the corresponding objects in your storyboard file.

```
open class WKInterfaceLabel : WKInterfaceObject {

    
    open func setText(_ text: String?)

    open func setTextColor(_ color: UIColor?)

    
    open func setAttributedText(_ attributedText: NSAttributedString?)
}
```

> 'init()' is unavailable

So, how can we use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) in watchOS with SwiftUI?

---

Side note:

Down the road, I expect the new [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) to reliably replace [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring), but as of watchOS 8 and iOS 15, AttributedString is [broken and incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746438/how-do-you-stroke-text-using-attributedstring-in-ios-15). This forces me to look for a solution to use NSAttributedString in watchOS with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to draw an image:

```
  func renderImage(_ attributedString: NSAttributedString, for width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let boundingRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: .infinity), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(boundingRect.size, false, 0)
    attributedString.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: boundingRect.size))
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return image
```

Then use it with Image()

```
        if let image = renderImage(longText, for: geometry.size.width) {
          Image(uiImage: image)
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

In latest swiftUI you can use `AttributedString` instead of `NSAttributedString`.

Details how to use it you can find in apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring

---

But still you can use NSAttributedString in swiftUI app in case of wrapping original NSTextField(macos) / UITextField(IOS) controls

Sample for macos wrapper (it's must be easy to rewrite) :

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
public struct AttributedText: NSViewRepresentable {
    private let text: NSAttributedString
    private let selectable: Bool
    
    public init(attributedString: NSAttributedString, selectable: Bool = true) {
        self.text = attributedString
        self.selectable = selectable
    }
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextField {
        let textField = NSTextField(labelWithAttributedString: text)
        textField.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = textField.frame.width
        textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true // Fix of clear of styles on click
        
        textField.isSelectable = selectable
        
        return textField
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ textField: NSTextField, context: Context) {
        textField.attributedStringValue = text
    }
}
```

But still in most cases better to use native way for SwiftUI -- `AttributedString`.

Comment: Unrelated to watchOS and WKInterfaceLabel

Comment: First part is just a link to Apple's document.  The second part, you haven't even tested using WKInterfaceLabel on watchOS. As the original question said, instantiating WKInterfaceLabel is not possible on watchOS.

Comment: @user5865651 Yep, first part is a link to appl's document that descibe AttributedString. All you need is to create AttributedString instance and do: `Text(attributedString: attributedStringInstance)` in your SwiftUI view. That's all.  Supported `watchOS 8.0+`. You just don't like my answer with no reason, that's all. And MORE OF THIS: I have wrote with LARGE text thet better to use AttributedString way, but not custom implementation.