# SwiftUI - is there a way to assign into Text an NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, nsattributedstring

So this is my VM:

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject, CryptoPopUpScreen {
var firstText: NSMutableAttributedString

init() {
    firstText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: L10n.pilotTitle, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Orion-Regular", size: 14)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ColorName.black])
 }
```

and i want to assign this text in the view like so:

```
struct TestView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image(viewModel.image).resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                            print(">> Trash Tapped")
                            //viewModel.dismiss
                        }) {
                            Image("closeBtn")
                        }.padding(.top, 30)
                            .padding(.trailing, 16),
                        alignment: .topTrailing
                        
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                
                Text(viewModel.firstText)
                
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
```

Couldn't find anything to handle this part of :

```
 .foregroundColor(viewModel.color)
 .font(viewModel.font)
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: SwiftUI 3 handles AttributedString directly but only with limited set of attributes, see  this for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/70746856/12299030. Native modifiers do not do anything with NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: @Asperi so the best way is using .foregroundColor(viewModel.color)
 .font(viewModel.font) and so ?

Comment: If you are only targeting iOS and want to get the full functionality of `NSAttributedString`, you can simply create a `UIViewRepresentable` over `UILabel` or `UITextView` and display your `NSAttributedString` in there.

Comment: @DávidPásztor tried it now and have a problem with it unfortunately:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73143584/swiftui-using-uiviewrepresentable-to-wrap-view-in-order-to-use-nsmutableattrib

Comment: take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73152473/14294561

Comment: There is an implementation of AttributedText on GitHub I believe at https://github.com/gonzalezreal/AttributedText that does what you want.